# Playframework: how change the value of a twirl parameters without reload the entire page?

Tags: playframework, twirl

Supose I have a view that receive a list of things like that:

```
@(notices: Seq[Notice])

@for( not <- notices) {
   <tr> not.title </tr>
}
....
```

and I have a method in a controller that its call by ajax and changes the values of the list. I know that de method can return a Result and re-render the page with the new values, like:

```
public Result editNotice() {
   /*change the list */
   return ok(list.render(notices);
}
```

But I want to refresh only the table where the list is.

How can refresh the list in the view without reload the entire page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved this returning the Result from the controller, but replacing the content in the html with javascript and a div.

**Controller:**

```
public Result editNotice() {
   return ok(table.render(notices);
}
```

**Html: list.scala.html**

```
@()

<div id="table">
</div>
<li>
    <a class="ajax-call" href="#table" onclick="$('#table').load('/editNotice';"/>
</li>
```

**Html: table.scala.html**

```
@(notices: Seq[Notice])
  <table>
     @for(not <- notices) {
       <tr><td>@not.title</td></tr>
     }
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create smaller view for rendering just the table part and use it in the `editNotice` action, then after receiving the AJAX response replace the existing one with JavaScript (probably jQuery)

To make sure, that you don't need to create the same table markup in two views keep in mind that you can use *include* template from the other one, like showed in [the docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaTemplateUseCases#Includes).

so your AJAX action will look like:

```
public Result editNotice() {
   return ok(table.render(notices);
}
```

and your `list.scala.html`:

```
@(notices: Seq[Notice])

@table(notices)
....
```

and your `table.scala.html`:

```
@(notices: Seq[Notice])

<table>
  @for(not <- notices) {
    <tr><td>@not.title</td></tr>
  }
</table>
```

**Other solution**

Is returning the JsonNode - array of objects - from the `editAction` and building new table with JS.

Comment: Thanks, but, the first option doesn't work correctly, cause if the method response only the @table view then only the table is rendered as a new page, not refreshing current one. The other solution really doesn't update the parameter...

Comment: This answer is some kind of concept (didn't test it) anyway can be managed for sure, without code for testing it's hard to create better sample :/